# How to make PDF1.5 with epstopdf?

Tags: pdftex, epstopdf

I have a couple of .eps-files that I include in my document with the `\includegraphics{}` macro. Obviously, this macro will call `epstopdf` that converts the .eps-file into .pdf, that will then be included.

Now, when compiling my document I see this in the log file:

```
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./symbols/sym_full_bridge_rectifier-eps-converted-to.pdf): PDF inclusion: found PDF version <1.7>, but at most version <1.5> allowed
```

Reading the epstopdf-manual on [this link](https://tug.org/epstopdf/epstopdf.html) I am informed that I can change the PDF-version of the converted files using the option `--gsopt=-dCompatibilityLevel=1.5`. This is easily done in a terminal. I have been looking for a way to globally alter ghostscript-options (in a .rc-file or similiar) but I fail.

So, how do I pass that option from within my LaTeX-document?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the command line used with `epstopdf` by declaring a new graphics rule for `eps` files.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.eps}{pdf}{.pdf}{%
  repstopdf --gsopt=-dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 #1 \OutputFile}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{example.eps}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Somehow this does not work for me. I still get complains about PDF1.7-files.

Comment: @bos, does `--gsopt=-dCompatibilityLevel=1.5` actually do what you want? If you convert the EPS directly with `epstopdf` do you get a PDF 1.7 or 1.5 file? If it's 1.5, then your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @bos, as far as I can see the default for `epstopdf` is PDF-1.5. So changing this setting shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: You're right. I ran `epstopdf` manually and got a PDF-1.5. So, something in my setup (Debian 9) makes `epstopdf` produce PDF-1.7 when invoked from `pdftex`. Trying to track it down seems like a big hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried the answer by David Purton. This did not work for me and gave the following error:

```
Package pdftex.def Error: File `figure-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found: using draft setting. \includegraphics{figure.eps}
```

I came up with the following solution by comparing the `epstopdf` commands in the log file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.eps}{pdf}{.pdf}{%
    epstopdf --gsopt=-dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 #1 --outfile=\OutputFile}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{figure.eps}
\end{document}
```

I tried to add a comment to David Purton's answer, because I do not think my answer is very different from his, but I do not have enough reputation to do that.

Comment: The difference is the `--outfile=`